# Alternative to auto-pst-pdf for chemnum

Tags: chemistry, ghostscript, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

Does anyone know what I could use instead of auto-pst-pdf combined with chemnum to replace tags in eps-files? Since this week it doesn't work anymore. Pstool (`\usepackage[mode=nonstop,crossref=true,crop=pdfcrop, process=all]{pstool}`) works halfway, but can't replace tags. Im currently using `\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off, cleanup=]{auto-pst-pdf}` and I'm getting a Ghostscript error.

```
\documentclass[ ngerman,11pt,
                paper=a4,
                listsfo=totoc,
                bibliography=totocnumbered,
                parskip=half,
                twoside=true,
                ]{scrbook}



\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}           
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{libertine}       
\usepackage{enumerate}


\usepackage{        
    caption,        
    graphicx,        
    wrapfig,         
}

\usepackage{chemcompounds} 
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\newcommand{\CNfig}[1]{\sffamily{\CNref{#1}}}
\usepackage{chemgreek}

\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off,cleanup=]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

plain text

\begin{figure}
 
   \replacecmpd[tag=TMP1]{1}
   \includegraphics{pic.eps}

\end{figure}

plain text with \cmpd{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to compile with `xelatex`? It doesn't require auto-pst-pdf.

Comment: Are all your graphics in eps format? If so typeset with latex(->drips->ps2pdf) rather than pdflatex and you won’t need to use auto-pst-pdf at all.

Comment: I use `pdfLatex` and I have many graphics in eps-format, but not all.

Comment: Can I just use xelatex instead of pdflatex or do I have to change some settings like shell-escape?

Comment: I think that this is related to [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574139/incompatibility-between-auto-pst-pdf-and-pdfpages-follow-up). Doesn't seem to be possible to use this feature with an up-to-date MiKTeX installation at present - at least if you're not willing to use one or another workaround provided by @Ulrike Fischer. While I love the .eps replacement by `chemnum`/`auto-pst-pdf`, this feature is broken every few months when some other package is updated.