# Incompatibility between auto-pst-pdf and pdfpages (follow-up)

Tags: pdfpages, incompatibility, compilation-error, auto-pst-pdf

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573216/18258) where @Ulrike Fischer [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573281/18258) that an outdated version of `eso-pic` was causing a compilation error when `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdfpages` are used. In the meantime, the MiKTeX package repository was updated and I now have `eso-pic` v3.0a installed. I'm still not able to compile the code below. However, the log looks different now.

The following code (which was working 2-3 months ago, before updating MiKTeX) does not compile using `pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex`. `--shell-escape` and `auto-pst-pdf` are required as I'm using the `chemnum` package in my real world example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{example-image-a.pdf}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also tried to include a true local .eps file instead of `example-image-b.eps` as I'm not exactly sure where this is included from. However, including something like `benzene.eps` ([click](https://pastebin.com/czr3jmNS)) did not change the compilation error during the `auto-pst-pdf` run (`mwe-autopp.log`):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.11) (preloaded format=latex 2020.12.8)  8 DEC 2020 15:02
entering extended mode
**\let \APPmakepictures \empty \input  mwe.tex
(mwe.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\c@figure=\count183
\c@table=\count184
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf\auto-pst-pdf.sty
Package: auto-pst-pdf 2020/10/08 v0.7 Wrapper for pst-pdf
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex" ("C:\Program Files\M
iKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX

Package shellesc Warning: Shell escape disabled on input line 73.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)

Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)
\c@app@runs=\count186
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty
Package: pst-pdf 2020/10/10 v1.2f PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\c@pspicture=\count187
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 105.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen139
\Gin@req@width=\dimen140
)
Package pst-pdf Info: MODE: 0 (dvi -- extraction mode) on input line 103.
No auxiliary output files.

(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2020/06/11 v0.70 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex (C:\U
sers\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex `pst-fp' v0.05
, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count188
\pstFP@xia=\count189
\pstFP@xib=\count190
\pstFP@xfa=\count191
\pstFP@xfb=\count192
\pstFP@rega=\count193
\pstFP@regb=\count194
\pstFP@regs=\count195
\pstFP@times=\count196
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks19
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen141
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen142
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks20
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks21
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks22
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Loading pgffor.code.tex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex" ("C:\Program F
iles\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex" ("C:\Program Files\MiKTe
X\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex"
\pgf@x=\dimen143
\pgf@xa=\dimen144
\pgf@xb=\dimen145
\pgf@xc=\dimen146
\pgf@y=\dimen147
\pgf@ya=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@yc=\dimen150
\c@pgf@counta=\count197
\c@pgf@countb=\count198
\c@pgf@countc=\count199
\c@pgf@countd=\count266
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count267
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count268
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen151
\pgfmath@count=\count269
\pgfmath@box=\box47
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex" ("C
:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.cod
e.tex") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.c
ode.tex") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex"))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.co
de.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen152
\pgffor@skip=\dimen153
\pgffor@stack=\toks26
\pgffor@toks=\toks27
)
\psLoopIndex=\count271
`PSTricks' v3.01  <2020/09/18> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen154
\pst@dimb=\dimen155
\pst@dimc=\dimen156
\pst@dimd=\dimen157
\pst@dimg=\dimen158
\pst@dimh=\dimen159
\pst@dimm=\dimen160
\pst@dimn=\dimen161
\pst@dimo=\dimen162
\pst@dimp=\dimen163
\pst@hbox=\box48
\pst@ibox=\box49
\pst@boxg=\box50
\pst@cnta=\count272
\pst@cntb=\count273
\pst@cntc=\count274
\pst@cntd=\count275
\pst@cntg=\count276
\pst@cnth=\count277
\pst@cntm=\count278
\pst@cntn=\count279
\pst@cnto=\count280
\pst@cntp=\count281
\@zero=\count282
\pst@toks=\toks28
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.con)
\psunit=\dimen164
\psxunit=\dimen165
\psyunit=\dimen166
\pst@C@@rType=\count283
\pslinewidth=\dimen167
\psk@startLW=\dimen168
\psk@endLW=\dimen169
\pst@customdefs=\toks29
\pslinearc=\dimen170
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen171
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen172
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen173
\everypsbox=\toks30
\psframesep=\dimen174
\pslabelsep=\dimen175
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen176
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen177
\pst@shift=\dimen178
)
File: pstricks.tex 2020/09/18 v3.01 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex)
File: pst-fp.tex 2020/09/18 v3.01 `PST-fp' (hv)
) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preview\preview.sty
Package: preview 2017/04/24 12.3 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/luatex85\luatex85.sty"
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preview\prtightpage.def
\PreviewBorder=\dimen179
)
\pr@snippet=\count284
\pr@box=\box51
\pr@output=\toks31
))) (C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pdfpages\pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2020/01/28 v0.5q Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count285
\calc@Bcount=\count286
\calc@Adimen=\dimen180
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen181
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count287
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/eso-pic\eso-pic.sty"
Package: eso-pic 2020/10/14 v3.0a eso-pic (RN)
\ESO@tempdima=\dimen182
\ESO@tempdimb=\dimen183
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen184
\AM@pageheight=\dimen185
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pdfpages\pppdftex.def
File: pppdftex.def 2020/01/28 v0.5q Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pdfpages\ppnull.def
File: ppnull.def 2020/01/28 v0.5q Pdfpages dummy driver (AM)

Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command
(pdfpages)                which will insert empty pages instead of the actual
(pdfpages)                PDF file because we are running in DVI mode or with
(pdfpages)                dvips driver.

))
\AM@pagebox=\box52
\AM@global@opts=\toks32
\AM@pagecnt=\count288
\AM@toc@title=\toks33
\c@AM@survey=\count289
\AM@templatesizebox=\box53
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvips.def"
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count290
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box55
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box56
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count291
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count292
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count293
)
No file mwe-autopp.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pdflscape\pdflscape.sty
Package: pdflscape 2019/12/05 v0.12 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\lscape.sty"
Package: lscape 2020/05/28 v3.02 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: dvips (dvips) on input line 124.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty"
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
))

Package pdfpages Warning: I cannot determine the number of pages of the
(pdfpages)                included document, because we are running in
(pdfpages)                DVI mode. 
(pdfpages)                You can use the option `lastpage' to give me a hint.

File: example-image-b.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<example-image-b.eps>
Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ps
,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<argument> ...box {\AM@ARBug@hook \AM@reflectbox {
                                                  \includegraphics [width=!,...
l.13     \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                              
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9640 strings out of 479698
 172042 string characters out of 2877001
 448672 words of memory out of 3000000
 26599 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 404193 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 316i,100n,425p,518b,2182s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `pdfpages` adds with the help of `eso-pic` code to the `shipout/background` hook.

Due to the order changes in the shipout routine this code is also there when preview tries to create the small pictures.

As a work around you can disable the eso-pic hook code for latex run. But long-term the preview package must be adapted to the new shipout handling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\ifpdf \else
\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}[eso-pic]
\fi

\begin{document}

\includepdf{example-image-a.pdf}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using this fix and the `hyperref` compatibility fix from [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2020-11/msg00000.html) finally allowed me to compile my real-world document again. I really hope that `preview` is fixed at some point in the near future... I guess that [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/jhi7nk/with_pdflatex_hyperref_breaks_autopstpdf/) is related to the same problem.

Comment: I am getting the feeling that [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565663/alternative-to-auto-pst-pdf-for-chemnum) is also related to the troubles with `preview` as discussed. Just for clarification: Does [your bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2020-11/msg00000.html) also cover the `preview` issues that are not related to the combination with `hyperref`?