# Package chemnum doesn't work for .eps files if hyperref is loaded

Tags: hyperref, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I wan't to use `chemnum` to number my chemicals in my document. The pictures are included as `.eps` files with temporary tags under the numbered structures. To acomplish that I use the `auto-pst-pdf` package mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) of `chemnum`.

The first problem I face is that after compiling the following appears in the compiler log

`C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 12: perl.exe c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=c:/Users/hugel/OneDrive/Desktop/mwe c:/Users/hugel/OneDrive/Desktop/mwe/mwe`

If i compile with `auto-pst-pdf` disabeled after recieving this message the right numbering shows up. Also in the `mwe-pics.pdf` file created after recieving the message the numbering is correct. This problem also appears if I'm not using chemnum.

As soon as I compile with the `hyperref` package loaded the `mwe-pics.pdf` file just shows a blank page and I get a `Float too large for page by 209.65544pt.` error.

It should look like the following picture:

[image]

The `test.eps` file looks like this:

[image]

Apparantly `auto-pst-pdf` is only needed wehen compiling with pdfLaTeX. Compiling with XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX gives me the following result:

[image]

Unfortunatley I dont't know how to upload the original `test.eps` file.

I'm using TexLive as distrbution and VSCodium as editor. I'm using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{auto-pst-pdf}%option "off" to disable the package
\usepackage{graphicx,chemnum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \replacecmpd{acid}
    \replacecmpd{alcohol}
    \replacecmpd{ester}
    \includegraphics{test}%test.eps located in the same folder as the .tex file
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: auto-pst-pdf doesn't work well anymore as the preview package has not been adapted to changes to latex. You can try some work arounds, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617267/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574157/2388, but I would avoid to use auto-pdf-pdf in a large document, better create small standalone graphics that you include in your document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also found an answer to my question here: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256723/hyperref-causes-error-in-auto-pst-pdf-used-by-chemstyle) I also tried to compile in XeLaTeX because apparently `auto-pst-pdf` is only needed when compiling in pdfLaTeX. The result is shown in my edited question. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: I think it is a misunderstanding that `auto-pst-pdf` is needed only for pdfLaTeX. In fact, you need the `auto-pst-pdf` for `psfrag` to work, which is what `chemnum` uses to change the tags (default `TMP1`, `TMP2`, ...). It is sad that this is broken and seemingly not be fixed. I have a document with 248 figures (`eps` files) that need replacements with `chemnum`. I will try to share the hacky fix I currently use, though this was breaking on several occasions with updated packages.